# What's the equal cmake variable of `llvm-config --system-libs all`?

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm using LLVM library with cmake by the `find_package` statement.

Here's part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
message(LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message(LLVM_DEFINITIONS: ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
message(LLVM_LIBRARIES: ${LLVM_LIBRARIES})
```

I found that `${LLVM_LIBRARIES}` is equal with `llvm-config --libs all`, what's the equal cmake variable of `llvm-config --system-libs all` ?

Comment: FYI: [github: llvm-config --system-libs not used](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags/issues/1105)

Comment: FYI: [SO: how to convert LLVM clang++ command line to cmake config?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52931852/7478597)